# What does $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ supported on $X$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, smooth-functions

I have a smooth function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The paper I am reading says "... for $F$ supported on $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$" where $X$ is some set that is an intersection of a closed set and an open set.

What does $F$ is supported on $X$ mean in this case?
Does it just mean that $F$ is non-zero on $X$ or the support of $F$ is the closure of $X$ or the support of $F$ contains the closure of $X$?
or something else even?

I wasn't too sure... any clarification would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I guess it means the *support* of $F$, i.e. the closure of the set of points $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbf R^n$ such that $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ne 0$, is contained in $X$.

Comment: You don't mean "contains X"?

Comment: No, I really think the support in contained in $X$ (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: @Bernard I see, ok, thank you!

Comment: You should provide more context. Although I tend to agree with Bernard, I would also argue that *usually* "$F$ is supported on $X$" means that $X$ is the support of $F$. However, $X$ seems to be not closed and that wouldn't make sense.